# HP EliteDesk 750 G5 with two DP monitors hangs when connecting third monitor via HDMI-to-VGA adapter

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I have a HP EliteDesk 750 G5 SFF PC which has two DisplayPort outputs and one HDMI. Currently I have two monitors connected to both DisplayPort connectors, yet I wanted to add a third screen connected to the HDMI port.

The third screen is an older screen which only supports VGA or DVI, so I took a basic HDMI-to-VGA/sound adapter and connected it to the HDMI output of the PC.

As soon as I plugged the adapter in, both monitors connected via DP went black, and the third monitor remained black as well. After unplugging the adapter, both monitors did not come back, and I couldn't do anything with my PC anymore. The only option left was to reboot.

I've tried this once more, but with the same results. Searching through the event logs didn't show anything even remotely related.

The HP PC has an AMD Radeon Vega 11, so I updated the drivers to the latest version and tried a third time, yet with the same result.

According to the documentation of the PC it should be able to support 3 screens (certainly at 1920x1080).

Why does this setup not work? Does anyone know of a solution? I've had a look through other questions, but none have the same issue. They're either running Windows 7 (I'm running Windows 10 21H2) or other, or only one monitor works, or the new monitor doesn't work. In my case, the entire setup fails.

Thanks.

Edit: I've dug out another monitor which does have HDMI input and connected this to my computer, and it works just fine. Therefor the problem is with the HDMI-VGA adapter, yet I don't know why.

Comment: If the monitor has DVI input then a simple HDMI-DVI cable (no conversion required) should be the logical choice.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately I don't have a HDMI-DVI cable at hand. I dug out another monitor that does support HDMI and attached that one to my computer, and it works just fine. So the cause must be in the HDMI-VGA adapter, but I'm afraid I don't understand why. I've updated my question to reflect my answer.